How to track bounced email addresses Marketing Cloud excluded from sends?
I know Marketing Cloud will excluded email addresses from sends if they bounce too many times. Is there a way I can track or change this before a send goes out.
I need to do urgent operational sends from time to time and there are always contacts excluded from the send because they have too many historical bounces.
An example is this contact who has had 3 bounced emails, and was marked as a bounced contact on 19/11/2023.

This is too long ago to use the Bounced Data View, but I can query the Contact Synchronised Data Extension against the IsEmailBounced, EmailBouncedDate, and EmailBouncedReason objects.
Is there a way to set the number of bounces before a contact is removed? Is it possible to query this bounced number against contacts at scale? And is querying the Synchronised Data Extension the best way to check for bounced contacts?

Bounce management is following some predefined set of rules, which is quite well described here. As you can see, the status on ALl Subscribers list changes, in case multiple bounces are experienced:

Three or more bounces, soft or hard, are received for the subscriber
and more than 15 days have passed since the first bounce. If the
bounce was from a trusted domain, only one hard bounce is required.

This is why you can always query your All Subscribers list to identify Held subscribers, who will not be sent to. In case only a single bounce has been experienced, status will only be Bounced and SFMC will still be trying to deliver emails.
You can identify Not Sent subscribers, by following this process. This will give you visibility into what recipients were withheld from a specific email send.
When it comes to rules for a Subscriber being marked as Held, it is not possible to update these, and you should refer to my first link for the exact logic (which can also be seen in this decision tree below).


Thanks, I looked at the links you send and put together a query I can use against a DE before a send goes out to get an idea of how many contacts will be held from the send:
SELECT s.EmailAddress, s.SubscriberKey, s.Status, s.BounceCount, s.DateUndeliverable
FROM ent._Subscribers s
JOIN [INSERT_DE] a on a.Contact_ID = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE Status IN ('unsubscribed','held','bounced')

This is a little broader than what you need. I've been doing transactional sends so unsubscribed contacts will still receive it, and Marketing Cloud will still send to bounced subscribers. I mostly want held contacts but it's good to know who might be at risk as well
